# How to save search engine entry to csv file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, export-to-csv

I am trying to make a search engine by comparing any search entry to my csv files. But i am not able to save my search entry into csv file. Below are my html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Search Engine</title>
  <meta name="viewreport" content="width=device-width", intial-scale=1>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>

   <div class="container">
    <h1 class = "title">Search Engine</h1>
    <form name="search" action="search.php" method="post">

     <div class="input-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" id="search">

     <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="gobtn" type="submit">Go!</button>

     <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
   </div>

    </form>

   </div>

  </body>
 </head>
</html>
```

And this is my search.php code

```
<?php
    $keys = array('search');
    $csv_line = array();
    foreach($keys as $key){
        array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);
    }
    $fname = 'search.csv';
    $csv_line = implode(',',$csv_line);
    if(!file_exists($fname)){$csv_line = "\r\n" . $csv_line;}
    $fcon = fopen($fname,'a');
    $fcontent = $csv_line;
    fwrite($fcon,$csv_line);
    fclose($fcon);
?>
```

Whenever I tried to search something, i kept on getting errors on the line array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]);

TQ in advance!

Comment: You should add more context. You want to append the searchterm to a .csv file? Which errors are you getting?

Comment: @JonasEberle yes, i wanted to save any searched terms into a csv file. The line in search.php, array_push($csv_line,'' . $_GET[$key]); gives error to me

Comment: Which error? Please be specific.

Comment: @JonasEberle when i input a search entry,which is health in this case, i got a Undefined index: health in C:\xampp\htdocs\searchengine\search.php on line 8

Comment: @JonasEberle i realized that i haven't initialized my $_GET[$key] which caused the error.

Comment: @JonasEberle is it possible for me to use python instead of php to do this? if yes can you tell me how?